# I-search prompt font

Tags: faces, minibuffer

I want my minibuffer prompt to be in bigger font, so I've added this to my `.emacs`:

```
(defun my-minibuffer-setup ()
  (set (make-local-variable 'face-remapping-alist)
       '((default :height 1.5))))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-minibuffer-setup)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

However, when I press <kbd>C-s</kbd>, the font size is the default 1 for some reason.

How to make the i-search prompt also in larger size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `isearch` does not use the minibuffer to read input from the user, rather it simply updates the echo area with the characters entered during `isearch`. Please note that the minibuffer and the echo area are **different**. From the [GNU Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Echo-Area.html)

> The echo area is used for displaying error messages (see Errors), for
>   messages made with the message primitive, and for echoing keystrokes.
>   It is not the same as the minibuffer, despite the fact that the
>   minibuffer appears (when active) in the same place on the screen as
>   the echo area.

As such `minibuffer-setup-hook` is never executed during `isearch` since the minibuffer is never setup.

In this specific case, `isearch-mode` [sets](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/isearch.el?id=59b5723c9b613f14cd60cd3239cfdbc0d2343b18#n924) `overriding-terminal-map` to [`isearch-mode-map`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/isearch.el?id=59b5723c9b613f14cd60cd3239cfdbc0d2343b18#n973) which binds all characters from in ascii range 32 to 255 to `isearch-printing-char` which updates the isearch prompt by echoing the new prompt.

If you follow the calls, you will find that `isearch-update` is used to update the prompt which `isearch-message-function` (if defined) to update the prompt otherwise it falls back to `isearch-message`. So a solution might be to set `isearch-message-function` to a custom function which calls `message` with a propertized string with `face` property set to custom face with desired height.

Following implements the idea mentioned in the previous paragraph, most of it is copied directly from the function `isearch-message` except for the last part where the string passed to message is propertized to have a larger height.

```el
(defun my-isearch-message (&optional c-q-hack ellipsis)
  ;; Generate and print the message string.
  (let ((cursor-in-echo-area ellipsis)
        (m isearch-message)
        (fail-pos (isearch-fail-pos t)))
    ;; Highlight failed part
    (when fail-pos
      (setq m (copy-sequence m))
      (add-text-properties fail-pos (length m) '(face isearch-fail) m)
      ;; Highlight failed trailing whitespace
      (when (string-match " +$" m)
        (add-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
                             '(face trailing-whitespace) m)))
    (setq m (concat
             (isearch-message-prefix ellipsis isearch-nonincremental)
             m
             (isearch-message-suffix c-q-hack)))
    (if c-q-hack m (let ((message-log-max nil)) (message "%s" (propertize m 'face  '(:inherit default :height 1.5)))))))

(setq isearch-message-function #'my-isearch-message)
```

Comment: @katspaugh I have added an example of setting `isearch-message-function`